# UserRepository is returning null in UserDetailsService but its working in other class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVt0D.png)

The springboot app is working, The users are adding but while login the username is going to loadusername but ,fetching data from database is returning null and it working in other class.I am trying from many days to resolve the issue, but i am not able to resolve the issue.

```
Userdetailserviceimplmn 


package com.ToDoList.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ToDoList.Entity.User;
import com.ToDoList.Repository.UserRepository;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;



@Service
public class Userdetailserviceimplmn implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired
     UserRepository  userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("User details ......");
        System.out.println(username + "......");
        System.out.println( "......");
        User userxyz =userRepository.getUserName(username);
                // Code is returning null here but its work fine in other class
        System.out.println(userxyz);
        
        if(userxyz == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not found user !!!");
        }
        
        userdetailsservice userdetailservice = new userdetailsservice(userxyz);
        return userdetailservice;
    }

}



userdetailsservice

package com.ToDoList.Configuration;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.ToDoList.Entity.User;

public class userdetailsservice implements UserDetails {
    
    private User user;
    
    

    public userdetailsservice(User user) {
        super();
        this.user=user;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}


------
WebConfig
---


package com.ToDoList.Configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class WebConfig{
    
    
    @Autowired
    private Userdetailserviceimplmn usercustom;
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        
    }
    
       @Bean
       public UserDetailsService getUserService() {
           return new Userdetailserviceimplmn();
       }
     
      
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
            
            System.out.println("AuthenticationManagerBuilder");
            System.out.println(usercustom);
            
            auth.userDetailsService(usercustom).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        } 
        
        
        
        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(getUserService());
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authProvider;
        }
        
        
        @Bean 
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/home","/login","loginvalidation").permitAll().requestMatchers("/tasks/**").authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginvalidation").defaultSuccessUrl("/tasks/dashboards").permitAll();
            
            DefaultSecurityFilterChain   securitych = http.build();
            
            return securitych;
        }
}


--
MainController
-

package com.ToDoList.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.ToDoList.Entity.User;
import com.ToDoList.Repository.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    
    @Autowired
    public UserRepository userrepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String HomePage(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("user",new User());
        System.out.println("Home page....");
        
        return "home";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String Login(Model model) {
        System.out.println("login page..... ");
                
        return "login";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/UserRegistration")
    public String UserRegistration(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,Model model) {
        
        try {
            System.out.print("user registration ......");
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userrepository.save(user);
            User usertest = userrepository.getUserName(user.getEmail());
            System.out.print(usertest.toString());
            
            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        model.addAttribute("user",new User());
          return "redirect:" + "/home";
    }
    
    

}


------
tasks.java
----


package com.ToDoList.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.ToDoList.Entity.User;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
public class tasks {
    
    @RequestMapping("/dashboards")
    public String dashboards(Model model) {
        
        System.out.print("task page   ...." );
        
        return "tasks";
    }

}


--
entity;-task.java
--

package com.ToDoList.Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tasks")
public class Tasks {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "Heading",nullable = false)
    private String Heading;
    
    @Column(name = "Description",nullable = false)
    private String Description;
    
    @Column(name = "Date",nullable = false)
    private String Date;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHeading() {
        return Heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        Heading = heading;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tasks [id=" + id + ", Heading=" + Heading + ", Description=" + Description + ", Date=" + Date
                + ", user=" + user + ", getId()=" + getId() + ", getHeading()=" + getHeading() + ", getDescription()="
                + getDescription() + ", getDate()=" + getDate() + ", getUser()=" + getUser() + ", getClass()="
                + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }


}

---
Entity:-User.java

--

package com.ToDoList.Entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id 
    private int SerialNo;
    
    
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String Email;
    
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String LastName;
    
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String Description;
    
    

    @Column(name = "Goal")
    private String Goal;
    
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String Password;
    
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Tasks> Tasks;

    public int getSerialNo() {
        return SerialNo;
    }

    public void setSerialNo(int serialNo) {
        SerialNo = serialNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getGoal() {
        return Goal;
    }

    public void setGoal(String goal) {
        Goal = goal;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public List<Tasks> getTasks() {
        return Tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Tasks> tasks) {
        Tasks = tasks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [SerialNo=" + SerialNo + ", Email=" + Email + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", LastName=" + LastName
                + ", Description=" + Description + ", Goal=" + Goal + ", Password=" + Password + ", Tasks=" + Tasks
                + "]";
    }   

}

----
UserRepositroy
---

package com.ToDoList.Repository;



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ToDoList.Entity.User;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User,String> {
    
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u  WHERE u.Email=:Email")
    User getUserName(@Param("Email") String Email);
}
```

---

`

__ I Used same user repository in main controller,its giving right solution.I am new in using spring security,I am doing login with database(Mysql)

Comment: `getUserName`? You mean `getUserByUserName`

Comment: Show your logs for `System.out.println(username + "......");`.

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes I created getusername in userrepository.i called getusername and it's returning null in userxyz and i am calling same in maincontroller than it's returning the data of user.